# Can't boot Acer laptop into Ubuntu 19.10 after dual boot install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10, 19.10

I've been stuck for 2 days on this.  I can't boot into Ubuntu after a fresh 19.10 install on my [Acer Aspire E15 E5-576 laptop](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/7332?b=1) . after I reboot there is no grub menu and it goes straight to Windows 10. What I've tried:

1. The steps reported here [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/88432#88432). Got no errors but it still doesn't show grub on startup.
2. Booted the live boot repair disk, performed the boot repair. Nothing changed.
3. Went into bios to change boot order but there is no grub option, only windows boot.
4. From windows cmd with admin rights entered

   ```
   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
   ```

   This worked. I can now see the grub menu and successfully boot into the Ubuntu partition. However I cannot access Windows 10 anymore. There is a Windows boot option in grub but if I select it, it loops into the grub menu forever.

   To go back into Windows I had to manually recreate the efi partition from the live Windows 10 disk, and after that, it boots straight to Windows 10 again.

I don't know what else to do. I'm in your hands. Thank you for your help

Comment: What brand/model system? Most often issue is Windows fast start up is on, or Windows needs chkdsk. Grub only boots working Windows, or Windows that is not hibernated. Fast start up sets hibernation flag. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: The laptop is Acer Aspire E 15. I tried with both fast start up on and off aswell as secure boot enable and disabled. There was no difference. When I was in ubuntu I could access the windows partition so there were no hibernation problems. I think the problem was when I overrode the boot file to use grubx64.efi so when I select windows boot it cycles back into grub. Makes sense?

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Acer (All models) has a unique requirement of setting "trust" on the Ubuntu UEFI entry. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 &

Comment: IT WORKED. First guide you posted worked like a charm. Can't believe I spent hours trying with grub update, repair utilities etc.. and it was acer security trust blocking it. Thank you so much. How do I accept it as answer?

Answer (score 2):

19.10 comes with a new version of [Grub 2.04 that many have reported bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1848892) with.

A common solution is to turn off [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) in BIOS. However other options are detailed in the bug reports and there other things to try if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have a recent model desktop ASUS motherboard, and upgrading the BIOS helped with the grub issues of 19.10

Answer (score 0):

windows loader is a bit finicky. i did the following, i don't know if this is the state-of-the-art way, but at least it worked.

if you had your boot files copied to the windows efi partition like i did, you can start windows, else you first have to use a live stick to copy your boot files to the windows efi partition. make sure you have grubx64.efi, shimx64.efi, mmx64.efi, grub.cfg and BOOTX64.CSV, in the directory

```
(windowsefi)/EFI/Microsoft/Boot
```

in windows you can mount the efi partition and copy the files with:

```
mountvol x: /s
```

then you have to change the default bootloader for windows to grub. for me it didn't work if the linux bootfiles were in any other directory than the one i mentioned.

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/shimx64.efi
```

shim is the shoehorn which puts grub into a system with secure boot enabled.

after a restart it should hopefully work.

Answer (score -1):

@oldfred has the best answer for OP Acer related issues. Typically for Acers, hold down the F2 key after booting to get to the boot settings [UEFI]. Then highlight 'security' menu, then down to highlight the option to trust a UEFI file.